# Swift check if object exists before append using Alamofire

Tags: arrays, swift, rest

I'm trying to verify if an object that comes from an API already exists in my array of objects, but I'm not being able to do that verification, Xcode keeps telling me that

```
Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'Cidades' operands
```

and my code is:

```
var cidades = [Cidades]()

    func findAllCidades(completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) {
        Alamofire.request(URL_CIDADESATIVAS, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in

            if response.result.error == nil {
                guard let data = response.data else {return}


                if let json = try? JSON(data: data) {
                    let results = json["results"].array

                    for item in results! {
                        let name = item["nome"].stringValue
                        let estado = item["estado"].stringValue
                        let id = item["id"].intValue

                        let cidade = Cidades(id: id, nome: name, estado: estado)
                        if(!self.cidades.index(where: { $0 == cidade})){
                            self.cidades.append(cidade)
                        }


                    }
                    completion(true)

                }

            } else {
                completion(false)
                debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check with the specific value the array contains with this, like if array contains `cidade` object with the same `id` then `if` condition will be true.

```
if self.cidades.contains(where: { $0.id == cidade.id}) {
     // found
} else {
     // not
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

`cidade` would not be indexed in `self.cidades` because of `cidade` in a newly created object. If you try to check then you need to compare a specific value.

```
let cidade = Cidades(id: id, nome: name, estado: estado)
if self.cidades.contains(where: { $0.id == cidade.id}) {
      self.cidades.append(cidade)
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Equatable protocol can be compared for equality using the equal-to operator (==)

Inside your model class past below code for Equatable

```
extension Cidades : Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Cidades, rhs: Cidades) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.nome == rhs.nome && lhs.estado == rhs.estado && lhs.id == rhs.id)
    }
```

And you can check object exists or not using your custom Equatable(==) function

```
let cidade = Cidades(id: id, nome: name, estado: estado)
        if self.cidades.filter({ c1 in c1 == cidade}).count > 0 {
            // Found
        }else{
            // Not found
        }
}
```

[Here is good resource by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable)